# Setting dynamic routes

Tags: php

I have a folder for tours in which i have different pages. Each page have a common form and every form is sending request to a twig file which is an email template. Now i need to set a dynamic path using Timber routes so that my mailjob should work.

Currently i am setting route like

```
\Timber::add_route('tours/', array($this, 'singletours'), array('methods'=>'POST'));
```

which is not working but if i set the route as

```
\Timber::add_route('tours/current-page-name', array($this, 'singletours'), array('methods'=>'POST'));
```

then it work for that specific page.

What would be the way to set a route that dynamically accept all the posts/pages that are under tours/

Comment: How is that related to Symfony2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok the issue is resolve now

What i did is set the route as

```
\Timber::add_route('tours/:name', array($this, 'singletours'), array('methods'=>'POST'));
```

and it worked :)